# Regex to check for at least 3 characters?

Tags: regex

I have this regex to allow for only alphanumeric characters.

How can I check that the string at least contains 3 alphabet characters as well.

My current regex,

```
if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(val))
```

I want to enforce the string to make sure there is at least 3 consecutive alphabet characters as well so;

```
111 // false
aaa1 // true
11a // false
bbc // true
1a1aa // false
```

Comment: use `{3,}` instead of `+`

Comment: @ka that would match at least three _characters_ not at least three _letters_ in any string.

Comment: It doesn't work 111 still is accepted.

Comment: {3,} means that the string must match a minimum of 3 characters. If you add a digit after the comma, that also sets a max limit.

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit.

Comment: Do the three alphabetic characters have to be consecutive?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To enforce three alphabet characters anywhere,

```
/(.*[a-z]){3}/i
```

should be sufficient.

**Edit.** Ah, you'ved edited your question to say the three alphabet characters must be consecutive. I also see that you may want to enforce that *all* characters should match one of your "accepted" characters. Then, a lookahead may be the cleanest solution:

```
/^(?.*[a-z]{3})[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Note that I am using the case-insensitive modifier `/i` in order to avoid having to write `a-zA-Z`.

**Alternative.** You can read more about [lookaround assertions here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). But it may be a little bit over your head at this stage. Here's an alternative that you may find easier to break down in terms of what you already know:

```
/^([a-z0-9]*[a-z]){3}[a-z0-9]*$/i
```

Comment: For those wishing to use this in a `grep` or `git grep` context, you'll need the `-E` option (a.k.a. `--extended-regexp`) for the `{n}` quantifier to be understood.

Answer (score 104):

`+` means "1 or more occurrences."

`{3}` means "3 occurrences."

`{3,}` means "3 or more occurrences."

`+` can also be written as `{1,}`.

`*` can also be written as `{0,}`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, it answers a comment to the question which itself does not answer the question.

Comment: True - but still VERY helpful to understand the logic of one of the previous answer(s).

Comment: A small addition:
`?` can be also written as `{0,1}`

Answer (score 10):

This should do the work:

`^([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){3,}[0-9]*$`

It checks for at least 3 "Zero-or-more numerics + 1 Alpha" sequences + Zero-or-more numerics.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match zero or more digits then 3 consecutive letters then any other number of digits?

`/\d*(?:[a-zA-Z]){3,}\d*/`

Answer (score 0):

This is vanilla JS you guys can use. My problem is solved using this.

```
const str = "abcdggfhf";
const pattern = "fhf";

if(pattern.length>2) {
console.log(str.search(pattern));
}
```