# regex : minimum total number of digits in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords, digit

I'm trying to know how many digits there is in a string that is essentially like a password.

For now I have this regex :

```
^(?=.*[0-9]{3,})([a-zA-Z0-9_/+*.-]{6,})$
```

It works great when their is 3 digits in a row but not when they are separated in the whole string.

I need to be able to know if there is 3 digit in strings like those :

> h123dasd 
>   1hkh/23jd
>   1gvbn/*2fefse-

What can I do ?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341016/regex-to-check-for-at-least-3-characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?=(?:\D*\d){3,})[a-zA-Z0-9_/+*.-]{6,}$/
```

This will enforce 3 digits in your input that may or may not be consecutive.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS4mL9/1)

Comment: That's clever and efficient

Comment: Thx a lot for that :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for such a complicated regex IMO - just extract digits from the string, concat the matches, and then check the length. Something like:

```
str.match(/\d+/g).reduce((p, c) => p + c).length > 3;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gw2q2dzo/1/)